# How to md5 in monotouch?

Tags: c#, asp.net, ios, xamarin.ios, md5

What's be best option for md5 hashing a string in monotouch?

Apparently traditional md5 don't work? http://lists.ximian.com/pipermail/monotouch/2009-October/001339.html

...and then checked by a ASP.net webservice.

Comment: That's quite an old bug, are you sure it's still valid?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The email you refer to is very old (more than two years) and this was fixed a long time ago.

`MD5`, like all other hash algorithms (e.g. `SHA1`, all SHA-2 family and `RIPEMD160`), are all available in MonoTouch. The same is true for HMAC, symmetric and asymmetric algorithms.

The right way to create a cryptographic instance in .NET is to use the factory of the base class, e.g.

```
MD5 hash = MD5.Create ();
```

This will ensure the best implementation will be used by your code (if many are available, e.g. if a native or hardware optimized version is available) and will help make your code more portable.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try doing `MD5 md5 = new MD5CryptoServiceProvider()`?